When shuffle in Spark becomes usefull?
From what I've read shuffle is used to increase parallelism, but it is very expensive.
For this reason I see that in a lot of cases (not sure if in most) users try to avoid shuffling or reduce it to the minimum with different approaches like broadcast, using functions that not causing shuffle.
When using these approaches you don't pay the penalty somewhere else?
There are still applications that using shuffle is useful?
Can we classify them to some specific field\use cases?
